# Xamarin Forms, Proper use of ListView

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, and am trying to create a page that has 4 sections of read-only data, one of which is a list of clickable items.  In addition, the top section needs to be stationary (always on top).

My initial attempt was to use various StackLayouts, with a ScrollView to control this.  There was much advice against putting a ListView in a ScrollView.  After some struggles I got it to work, but then ran into an odd app crash on the ListView binding the second time a page is loaded (simple labels with the same binding are fine).

So my question is, should a ListView be used when many other elements are also on the page?  If so, should the header and footer of the ListView contain the other controls, effectively making the ListView the root control?  Is there an alternative suggestion to get a bound, clickable list on a page with other controls?  Or maybe I'm running into difficulty simply due to the ListView needing to be in a ScrollView?

Comment: You can always create special row templates for the "static" data, in this way you will only need to use a listview as the root. But, that said, I have some listviews inside scrollviews, and there's no problem the problem is an usability problem because the scrolling is worse because you can try to scroll the list and move the scrollviewcontent or viceversa. So the exception rebinding the data should be a bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this insight.  The crash issue I have was due to a known bug (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42678).  Changing the ListView CachingStrategy to RecycleElement fixed it.  I'll give the row templates a try - and glad to know the usability risks you pointed out.